# Trying to understand the difference between "any([comprehension])" and "any(comprehension)"

Tags: python

Is there any difference between:

```
if any([value % 2 for value in values]):
    print('done')
```

and

```
if any(value % 2 for value in values):
    print('done')
```

where values is an array of 0-20?

I know that `any()` checks to see if any value in the array meets the requirement, but want to know if there is any difference between the functions.

Comment: By the way you need to specify a condition such as `value % 2 == 0`

Comment: @imM4TT no, it's not necessary

Comment: It's a bit confusing in this case, without an explicit statement it's actually looking for odd numbers

Answer (score 9):

The first one computes the entire list first, and then apply `any`. The second one, on the other hand, is "lazy"; if some element is truthy, `any` returns `True` immediatly, without going further.

```py
def foo(x):
    print(f"foo({x}) is called!")
    return x >= 5

print(any([foo(x) for x in range(10)]))
# foo(0) is called!
# foo(1) is called!
# foo(2) is called!
# foo(3) is called!
# foo(4) is called!
# foo(5) is called!
# foo(6) is called!
# foo(7) is called!
# foo(8) is called!
# foo(9) is called!
# True

print(any(foo(x) for x in range(10)))
# foo(0) is called!
# foo(1) is called!
# foo(2) is called!
# foo(3) is called!
# foo(4) is called!
# foo(5) is called!
# True
```

As you can see, the second one does not evaluate `foo(x)` for `x > 5`, since `any` has already found `foo(5) == True`, which is enough to say the result is `True`.

Comment: So would it be fair to say that the time complexity for the first one is O(n) while the time complexity for the second one is O(1)?

Comment: Not really - it could be going to the end to find the fist `Truth`

Answer (score 5):

The difference between the two are that the first constructs a temporary list from as long as `values` and then passes it on to `any()` (and then deletes it). The second is using what is called a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) which will iteratively calculate and yield *as needed* and passed them on to `any()`. Because of the way `any()` works, it may stop doing this before reaching the end because the condition has been satisfied. For very large datasets the latter will require significantly less memory to complete (and potentially less processor time if it stops "early").